# Join calendar table with data table and fill in blank data

Tags: sql, datetime, left-join, hiveql, cross-join

I have a dataset like this:

```
 Date               TopicName           Count
 10/18/2020          Topic 1              5
 10/19/2020          Topic 1              6
 10/19/2020          Topic 2              3
```

I also have a regular calendar table that just has a date value for each day.

```
 Date 
 10/18/2020
 10/19/2020
```

What I need is to join these two tables and for each TopicName have a row for every day from the calendar table. If there's no data for that date/topic, then leave "Count" as null

So what I want is this:

```
 Date               TopicName           Count
 10/18/2020          Topic 1               5
 10/18/2020          Topic 2               null
 10/19/2020          Topic 1               6
 10/19/2020          Topic 2               3
```

I have tried many variations of left outer join, full outer join, cross join, but I can't get it to work. There is never a row for 10/18 Topic 2. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: CROSS JOIN calendar table and topics. OUTER JOIN that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cross join`  the calendar with the list of distinct topics available in the table, and then bring the actual dataset with a `left join`:

```
select c.date, x.topicname, t.cnt
from calendar c
cross join (select distinct topicname from mytable) x
left join mytable t 
    on t.date = c.date and t.topicname = x.topicname
```

Note: `count` is a language keyword, I used `cnt` instead.

Ideally, you would have a separate table to store the topics, that you could use instead of the `select distinct` subquery.